# Java sign and Javascript verify a signature failed

Tags: javascript, java, signature

I am trying to use Java to sign a message on the server side, while verify the signature on the client side, but failed! My steps are as follows:

1. Generate RSA key pair:

   `openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048`
   `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in privatekey.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt`
   `openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -pubout -outform DER -out pubic_key.der`

Thus I got `pubic_key.der` and `private_key.der` two files.

2. Using java to load these two files and generate signature.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.*;

public class SignatureTest {

    public static KeyPair generateSignKeyPair() throws Exception {
        byte[] privBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testFiles/private_key.der"));
        byte[] pubBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testFiles/public_key.der"));

        // private key
        KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        //public key
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubBytes);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
        return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
    }

    public static byte[] generateSignature(PrivateKey signPrivateKey, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        dsa.initSign(signPrivateKey);
        dsa.update(data);
        return dsa.sign();
    }

    public static boolean verifySignature(PublicKey publicKey, byte[] data, byte[] sig) throws Exception {
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        dsa.initVerify(publicKey);
        dsa.update(data);
        return dsa.verify(sig);
    }

    private static String getPEMPrivateKeyFromDER(PrivateKey privateKey) {
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        String begin = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
        String end = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey.getEncoded());
        String key = new String(base64.encode(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded()));
        return begin + "\n" + key + "\n" + end;
    }

    private static String getPEMPublicKeyFromDER(PublicKey publicKey) {
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        String begin = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String end = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
        String key = new String(base64.encode(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded()));
        return begin + "\n" + key + "\n" + end;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        try{
            KeyPair keyPair = generateSignKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            // print private key
            String privKey = getPEMPrivateKeyFromDER(privateKey);
            System.out.println("privKey:\n " + privKey);

            // print public key       
            String pubKey = getPEMPublicKeyFromDER(publicKey);
            System.out.println("pubKey:\n " + pubKey);

            System.out.println("---------------Convert to JWK-----------------");
            RSAKey jwk = new RSAKey.Builder((RSAPublicKey) publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).build();

            System.out.println("jwk:\n" + jwk.toPublicJWK());

            String data = new String(base64.encode("hello".getBytes()));

            // sign "hello"
            byte[] sig = generateSignature(keyPair.getPrivate(), "hello".getBytes());
            System.out.println("signature base64: " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sig)));

            // start verify
            boolean result = verifySignature(publicKey, "hello".getBytes(), sig);
            System.out.println("Verification: " + result);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the public key, private key, signature and jwk are as follows:

- public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0pGjaaEsFCYj3sjfYzTarJPgYgSGtuwMeCMgfzAEFy0va+R83tyRNy7asYtGFB8mpwaED9OvzVJ3JvJKCE81c6Q6yWoZ+xQEzMtvQ3FibH/MH+gBSkgRYczP+dsT9j3n+F6sIRz9qdHfzHCyDPZ0tSf/wmmsX54eayMuH1p417bHv9yysDgXYxWKWiOoYOP6ynYSqMLEIxirkgUYlhsXVTD4RlZOAVBCUIbN2YE41UnQDExEnw6s8u1KHDeiNc15G1zZmm4SX/BNOWEeGjEVB4VJAwTUynaAcGgcBuNxzadpklLqFNYyIbu3WkK8L1Im3vVAuttMYIFF7sWiWLiFDQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

- private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
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
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- signature:

```
signature base64: sor4eqf2iBiqJnhMogu2GSx0JlT804l9J4thEkZ6stPZLari3sFa6w1/kxtwR+ogHq+LJM2g25eygTPr6RqndOiVjWnB7l0btnPV+wN4AWzofBSi+vAXL+BA+ANm8QF14JG0yW2acF+Wyn+xZjMid6tCc1IVw/3EOdVGWVATVYigM6HCVxdXE9HLBuj0VK7suWgseAEfxrn5hbzaJT+OxZ4Ozx3YwwyUjeDy62cnirswOMb49bZ7eLEreffCZLnah1URrerXTikFyDSFslZjg4X19q4MArZ+xqm8ON+tLC4NoQw7ST9f7KcYznbw58oEgpvE2mxdiEbsTqWwJ+/BOQ==
```

- jwk (JSON Web Key):

```
{"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"0pGjaaEsFCYj3sjfYzTarJPgYgSGtuwMeCMgfzAEFy0va-R83tyRNy7asYtGFB8mpwaED9OvzVJ3JvJKCE81c6Q6yWoZ-xQEzMtvQ3FibH_MH-gBSkgRYczP-dsT9j3n-F6sIRz9qdHfzHCyDPZ0tSf_wmmsX54eayMuH1p417bHv9yysDgXYxWKWiOoYOP6ynYSqMLEIxirkgUYlhsXVTD4RlZOAVBCUIbN2YE41UnQDExEnw6s8u1KHDeiNc15G1zZmm4SX_BNOWEeGjEVB4VJAwTUynaAcGgcBuNxzadpklLqFNYyIbu3WkK8L1Im3vVAuttMYIFF7sWiWLiFDQ"}
```

**In java, the verification is true!!!**

3. In the client side, I use Webcrypto to verify:

```
// npm install @trust/webcrypto --save
const crypto = require('@trust/webcrypto');

// Utility function
function str2ab(str) {
  var arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
  for (var iii = 0; iii < str.length; iii++) {
    bytes[iii] = str.charCodeAt(iii);
  }
  return bytes;
}

// The publicKeyB64 is in the form of jwk that output in the step 2
var publicKeyB64 = {"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"0pGjaaEsFCYj3sjfYzTarJPgYgSGtuwMeCMgfzAEFy0va-R83tyRNy7asYtGFB8mpwaED9OvzVJ3JvJKCE81c6Q6yWoZ-xQEzMtvQ3FibH_MH-gBSkgRYczP-dsT9j3n-F6sIRz9qdHfzHCyDPZ0tSf_wmmsX54eayMuH1p417bHv9yysDgXYxWKWiOoYOP6ynYSqMLEIxirkgUYlhsXVTD4RlZOAVBCUIbN2YE41UnQDExEnw6s8u1KHDeiNc15G1zZmm4SX_BNOWEeGjEVB4VJAwTUynaAcGgcBuNxzadpklLqFNYyIbu3WkK8L1Im3vVAuttMYIFF7sWiWLiFDQ"};

// the Base64 output of "hello"
var dataB64 = "aGVsbG8=";

// The signature output from step 2
var signatureB64 = "sor4eqf2iBiqJnhMogu2GSx0JlT804l9J4thEkZ6stPZLari3sFa6w1/kxtwR+ogHq+LJM2g25eygTPr6RqndOiVjWnB7l0btnPV+wN4AWzofBSi+vAXL+BA+ANm8QF14JG0yW2acF+Wyn+xZjMid6tCc1IVw/3EOdVGWVATVYigM6HCVxdXE9HLBuj0VK7suWgseAEfxrn5hbzaJT+OxZ4Ozx3YwwyUjeDy62cnirswOMb49bZ7eLEreffCZLnah1URrerXTikFyDSFslZjg4X19q4MArZ+xqm8ON+tLC4NoQw7ST9f7KcYznbw58oEgpvE2mxdiEbsTqWwJ+/BOQ==";

var signatureAlgorithm = {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]), hash: {name: 'SHA-256'}};

var data = str2ab(Buffer.from(dataB64, 'base64').toString());
var signature = str2ab(Buffer.from(signatureB64, 'base64').toString());

crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", publicKeyB64, signatureAlgorithm, false, ["verify"]).then(function(pubkey){
        console.log("pubkey: " + pubkey);
        return crypto.subtle.verify(signatureAlgorithm, pubkey, signature, data);                    
}).then( function (valid) {
    console.log("Signature valid: ----- " + valid + " -----");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Verification failed: \n" + err );
});
```

4. The result shows:

`Signature valid: ----- false -----`

I am wondering I made mistake in any step and could anyone help with this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: alternative to your str2ab: `new Uint8Array([...str].map(v => v.charCodeAt()));`... but you start with a buffer, why would you even `.toString()` only to then unstring it again? Why not `const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(dataB64, 'base64'));`? Doing so means removing `str2ab` as possible source of problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!!!@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. The `str2ab` is redundant, using the `const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(dataB64, 'base64'));` solves the problem.